# Why "city life" is correct not "city's life"?

Tags: grammar

I have noticed that always "city life" is used. Why "city's life" is not used?

Comment: "city life", "London nightlife", etc. are ***noun adjunct*** constructions, where the first "noun" is being used adjectivally to modify the second. It's a common usage in English - for example, we nearly always refer to a ***car radio***, not a ***car's radio***.

Comment: I can see lots of Google hits for "city's life". It relates to whether you're talking about a particular city or the general life connected with cities in general.

Comment: Thanks for comments. I think those comments answer my question.

Comment: Because cities are  not alive (barring https://www.benaaronovitch.com/). *City* is used as an adjective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are grammatically correct, but they have different meanings. As this [NGram graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=city%20life%2C%20city%27s%20life&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) shows, one is very much more widely used than the other.

City life is a compound noun that refers to the kind of life one experiences in a city, in the same way that a cement mixer is a kind of mixer that is used for cement.

[the/a] City's life is another way of talking about the life of [the/a] city, and would refer to the kind of life that a city might have. This construction might be used if one were to anthropomorphize a city, for example

> What Memphis needs primarily, in order to solve her school building problem, is a realization of the fact that providing for the present and future growth of school population is an engineering problem that demands the same deliberation and farsighted planning which *she* has so well displayed in other phases of the **city's life**. - *Training Little Children, Charles Riborg Mann et al, 1902*

Answer (score 1):

'City life' idiomatically refers to the shared *experience* of living in a city. This particular use of 'life' does not mean the *condition* of life (ie being alive) or to *instances* of life (ie the presence of living things).

'City's life' is not idiomatic. The possessive would make this mean life belonging to the city. A city is not literally alive (though that is a common metaphor) and we don't speak of humans collectively as 'life' in the same way that we do different kinds of animals (for example, '*sea life*' refers collectively to all different types of creatures that typically live in the sea).